# Flutter #3: I have some async problem in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, async-await, flutter-layout

I have a piece of code to scan and read device information. I have printed the elements in the list in `onScan` function, however I don't know how to get that information and put it in a `listview`.

Can someone help me?

```
List<Data> listDevice = [];
  Future<void> getData() async {
    var apiEndpoint = TTAPI.shared;
    await apiEndpoint.devideScan(((data) => onScan(data)));
  }
```

> 

```
Future<void> onScan(dynamic data) async {
    var dataResponse = DataResponse.fromJson(data);
    print(dataResponse.toJson());
    List<dynamic> dt = jsonDecode(jsonEncode(dataResponse.data).toString());
    dt.forEach((element) {
      var item = Data.fromJson(element);
      print(item.modelName);
      listDevice.add(item);
    });
    var connectRequest = {
      'serialNumber': 'DEVICE_SERIAL',
      'modelName': 'DEVICE_MODEL',
      'ipAddr': 'DEVICE_IP'
    };
    var apiEndpoint = TTAPI.shared;
    await apiEndpoint.connectDevice(connectRequest);
  }
```

> 

```
Future<List<Data>> getList() async {
    return listDevice;
  }
```

> 

You can see more of my code here: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1ntxaDpyNCLD1MyzJOTmZsrh7-Jfim8cm0Va86IQZGww/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

As for the current code structure, `listDevice` is populated inside Future. So you can call setState to update the UI after getting the list at the end of `onScan`.

```dart
 Future<void> getData() async {
    var apiEndpoint = TTAPI.shared;
    await apiEndpoint.devideScan(((data) => onScan(data)));
  setState((){});
 }
```

But it would be great to use [`FutureBuilder`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html) and return list from `getData`.

Current question pattern  example

```dart
class TextFW extends StatefulWidget {
  const TextFW({super.key});

  @override
  State<TextFW> createState() => _TextFWState();
}

class _TextFWState extends State<TextFW> {
  //for current question way
  List<int> listDevice = [];

  Future<void> getData() async {
    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 2));

    /// others async method
    listDevice = List.generate(10, (index) => index);
    setState(() {}); //here or `getData().then()`
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getData();
    // or this  getData().then((value) => setState((){}));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: listDevice.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) => ListTile(
          title: Text("${listDevice[index]}"),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Using FutureBuilder

```dart
class TextFW extends StatefulWidget {
  const TextFW({super.key});

  @override
  State<TextFW> createState() => _TextFWState();
}

class _TextFWState extends State<TextFW> {
  /// method will provide data by scanning
  Future<List<int>> getData() async {
    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 2));
    return List.generate(10, (index) => index);
  }

  late final fututre = getData();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: FutureBuilder<List<int>>(
        future: fututre,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return Text("${snapshot.error}");
          }
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            final listDevice = snapshot.data;
            return ListView.builder(
              itemCount: listDevice?.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) => ListTile(
                title: Text("${listDevice![index]}"),
              ),
            );
          }
          return CircularProgressIndicator();
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you be more specific about setState in this case? It would be great if there was a specific example.

Comment: Yes, I totally agree with this, That's why I've included FutureBuilder option